How to prevent an element from being split between pages when exporting to PDF using react-to-pdf?
I am using the react-to-pdf library to export a specific div element as a PDF. However, when the content spans multiple pages, some elements are being split between pages (e.g., half of the element appears on one page and the other half on the next page).
Is there a way to avoid this, so that if an element would be split, it automatically moves to the next page instead? I'm looking for a solution to keep the content intact across pages.
Any help would be appreciated!
What I tried:
I tried adjusting CSS properties like page-break-inside: avoid; on the elements inside the div, hoping this would prevent them from being split across pages. However, this didn't seem to have any effect when exporting to PDF using the react-to-pdf library.
What I expected:
I was expecting the react-to-pdf library to automatically handle page breaks or for CSS properties like page-break-inside to prevent elements from being split across pages. Ideally, if an element doesn't fit completely on one page, it should be moved to the next page without splitting.
